# Maven Error While Creating java Project using Command Line

Tags: java, maven

I got error while creating new java project using maven. I have set all of the envrionmnet variable and now going to create a project using maven cammand. when i use this command i got build failure error.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.tutorial.test -DartifactId=hellowrld 
-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
```

Please help me. Is i missing something?

This is the whole output

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...                                                 
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1: 
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.3.1/maven-install-plugin-2.3.1.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1: 
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.3.1
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7                      
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.0/maven-site-plugin-3.0.pom                                       
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.0                            
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3                      
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom                 
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5                                                                           
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.1/maven-dependency-plugin-2.1.pom 
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.1          
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.0/maven-release-plugin-2.0.pom                                 
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.0                   
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. 
Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org                                                          
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. 
Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 12.696s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue May 21 05:33:14 ACT 2013                                [INFO] Final Memory: 2M/127M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\waqas.ali\.m2\repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: First i see that you are using **create** instead of **generate** furthermore it's hard to guess what's without the error messages.

Comment: i have also use generate but got same error. i am using command prompt and didn't know how to copy that error

Comment: What error? Please show the output..complete output!

Comment: what is difference between create and generate command

Comment: [*create*](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/usage.html) is deprecated so don't use it anymore

Comment: got this error " No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project....

Comment: Have you tried to run `mvn archetype:generate` without any parameters?  furthermore can you post the full output of the run...

Comment: [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/eugene/.m2/repository), central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

Comment: I run this command with and without parameter

Comment: Do you have Internet connection at the time of running this command? Does Maven report problem with downloading plugins and artefacts?

Comment: Yes i have internet connection that's why i think i am able to post my problem at stackoverflow.

Comment: just download the required artifacts and place it in your local repo. Maven generally downloads the artifacts from the internet.

Comment: Maven give warning at the start that "Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for the org.apache.maven.plugin:maven-clean-plubin:2.4.1:.......

Comment: how did i download these artifacts? i didn't know anything about maven

Comment: Remove your local repository and retry it from scratch.

Comment: local repository means remove maven files and deleted envrionment variable?

Comment: local repo is the location where all the artifacts that maven downloads are placed.

Comment: There is no such directory. no artifact is downloaded after that command.

Comment: one more thing when i use this command " mvn -version" i got this " 
Maven home: D:\apache-maven-3.0.5
Java version: 1.6.0, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows vista", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." is this expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are behind a proxy, try using the below command

`mvn -DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=myproxy.com -DproxyPort=3128 archetype:generate`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This command i used for creating Spring project for WS and successfully created also .

```
mvn archetype:create -DarchetypeGroupId=org.springframework.ws -DarchetypeArtifactId=spring-ws-archetype -DarchetypeVesrion=1.0.0 -DgroupId=com.mytutorial -DartifactId=simpleWeb2
```

Hope this will help.